# Current token (START_OBJECT) not of boolean type - elasticsearch bulk insert

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following vanilla Node.js code:

```js
  const lst = vals.map(v => {
    return [{index: {}}, {value: v}];
  });

  const flt = flattenDeep([lst]);

  req.post('/foo/_bulk', {}, flt, (err, v) => {
    log.info(err,v);
  });
```

I am getting this error:

> Current token (START_OBJECT) not of boolean type

in detail:

```
   app:es ERROR  {   errors: true,   items: [
    {
      index: {
        _id: '4Z6ZS20Bd2MYc8MzjK-O',
        _index: 'foo',
        _type: '_doc',
        error: {
          caused_by: {
            reason: 'Current token (START_OBJECT) not of boolean type\n' +
              ' at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@4c9fb11; line: 1, column: 11]',
            type: 'i_o_exception'
          },
          reason: "failed to parse field [value] of type [boolean] in document with id '4Z6ZS20Bd2MYc8MzjK-O'. Preview of field's value: '{date=unknown, @bunion=true, level=WARN, appName=unknown, @version=-1, host=unknown, pid=-1, _id=5d83fe5878bbe129e1cf9444, fields=null, value=foo}'",
          type: 'mapper_parsing_exception'
        },
        status: 400
      }
    }   ],   took: 5 }
```

does anyone know why it doesn't like my array? The `lst` array only has one element:

```
[{index:{},{value:'foo'}]
```

so why would that cause a problem?

If I change it to:

```
  const lst = vals.map(v => {
    return [{index: true}, {value: v}];
  });
```

then I get this error instead:

> Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT or
>   END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_BOOLEAN]

flt object looks like this:

```
 flt: [
    {
      index: {}
    },
    {
      value: {
        '@bunion': true,
        '@version': -1,
        _id: 5d84039dc98ff82d30337e6c,
        appName: 'unknown',
        date: 'unknown',
        fields: null,
        host: 'unknown',
        level: 'WARN',
        pid: -1,
        value: 'foo'
      }
    }
  ]
```

and then I write the array to the request like so:

```js
  for (const v of flt) {
    req.write(JSON.stringify(v));
    req.write('\n');
  }
```

ok so it works when I do this:

```js
  const lst = vals.map(v => {
    return [{index: {}}, {value: true}];  // value is boolean now!
  });
```

but why??

Comment: Could you please post an `flt` values and how it structured and also index mapping too?

Comment: Sure, it should be the same array, flattened, but I will check

Comment: ok I updated the OP, thanks for helping

Comment: Data need to be structured in a specific way for a `bulk api`. Please check this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: This is the format
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }

Comment: thanks, I updated the OP, I got the error to go away, but I am not inserting the value that I want to insert.

Comment: Please post updated details in question. So then I can help you out.

Comment: thanks, I think I got the answer, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it looks like it worked when I did this:

```
  const lst = vals.map(v => {
    return [{index: {}}, {create: v}];
  });
```

the response was:

> ```
> app:es INFO  result: {
>   errors: false,
>   items: [
>     {
>       index: {
>         _id: '6J7ZS20Bd2MYc8Mzya82',
>         _index: 'foo',
>         _primary_term: 2,
>         _seq_no: 72,
>         _shards: {
>           failed: 0,
>           successful: 2,
>           total: 2
>         },
>         _type: '_doc',
>         _version: 1,
>         result: 'created',
>         status: 201
>       }
>     }
>   ],
>   took: 31
> }
> ```

ok, maybe not, now everything is inside a property called "create":

[image]

Ok so I figured out the **problem**. The **problem** is that ES has a crappy API. If your object has a property called "value", then ES expects it to be a boolean.  So the answer seems to be to wrap your data in a safe key, maybe not "create" but something short like "val" (but not "value").

Comment: Are you trying to insert new values or updating it?

Comment: I am trying to insert

Comment: instead of it being `{_source:{create:x}}`  I just want it to be `{_source:x}` ... this is crazy, this API sucks :(

Comment: No its not. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk API data should be formatted like below

```
{"index" : {}}
{"name": "Carlson Barnes", "age": 34}
{"index":{}}
{"name": "Sheppard Stein","age": 39}
{"index":{}}
{"name": "Nixon Singleton","age": 36}
{"index":{}}
{"name": "Sharron Sosa","age": 33}
{"index":{}}
{"name": "Kendra Cabrera","age": 24}
{"index":{}}
{"name": "Young Robinson","age": 20}
```

So change the code like this

```
  const lst = vals.map(v => {
    return [{index: {}}, v];
  });
```

Kibana UI example

Insert operation

[image]

And its output

[image]

Comment: doesn't work, first `v` is the object, so it should just be  `const lst = vals.map(v => ( [{index: {}}, v));`, but that gives me an error

Comment: OP. Updated my answer.

Comment: I think I know why..my object `v` has a property called "value" and goddamn ES expects "value" to point to a boolean.

Comment: Do you have a mapping for the index?

Comment: I upvoted, because this will work for some people. But this will cause the error described in the OP if `v.value` does not point to a boolean.

Comment: Thank you. Please post a sample data. So then I can test it in local. And also ES version and mapping details too.

Comment: The sample data is in the OP, the `flt` object/array...notice how `"value"` points to `"foo"` instead a boolean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199710/discussion-between-sathishkumar-rakkiasamy-and-mrcholo).

Comment: From my test, the error caused not because of value field. It may caused by the format of data. Also try to use the Elastic JavaScript SDK instead of using plain JS,